# 3 Node mongo db authentication setup fails

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 node mongodb replica set as below

Primary node Secondary node Arbiter node

Replication set is enabled for all three. I am trying to set up authentication for these nodes and i followed the below steps to configure it.

Step 1: Created a root user, added him to role: root with password in the primary node

Step 2: Created a key file using the command - openssl rand -base64 741 > mongodb.key in the primary node and copied the key file to all the 3 nodes

Step 3: Added the below configuration to all three nodes.

Security: authorization: enabled keyFile: /pathtokeyfile

Step 4: sudo service mongod restart, on all three nodes

After completing above steps i tried accessing the DB with username and password in the primary node and i could read the DB and files

When i try the same in secondary and arbiter nodes i get the below error

> rsss0:SECONDARY> show dbs
>   2019-03-06T09:10:40.884+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases failed:{
>       "operationTime" : Timestamp(1551863438, 9),
>       "ok" : 0,
>       "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
>       "code" : 13435,
>       "codeName" : "NotMasterNoSlaveOk",
>       "$clusterTime" : {
>           "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1551863438, 9),
>           "signature" : {
>               "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
>               "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
>           }
>       }
>   } :
>   _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
>   Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:67:1
>   shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:860:19
>   shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:750:15
>   @(shellhelp2):1:1

Answer (score 4):

As shown in your question you are now connected with the secondary node. Since secondary may contain stale data, by default MongoDB won't allow you to read any data from secondary.
There are two options to read your data

1. Connect primary node (use the correct port number )
2. From secondary, run `rs.slaveOk()`. This will allow you to read data from the secondary.

Note: run `rs.status()` or `rs.isMaster()` to find out which one is primary.

Comment: When I try to enable authentication the secondary DB node is in recovery state but as soon as I disable auth , then it works fine. How to enable authentication for 3 node replicaset

Comment: Recovery mode means the node was trying to catch up with the primary. It is nothing to do with authentication. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-states/#replstate.RECOVERING

Comment: Just using internal authentication(in this case Keyfile) you already using will enable client authorization by default. So no need to explicily enable authentication when using keyFile(internal) authentication. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/ Check the Note on the link

Comment: I enabled auth on secondary and restarted the mongod service and in primary I did not enable auth yet. So once after recovering get over in secondary should I enable auth on primary or I sould enable auth on all the servers at once shot ?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly specify the authentication when you use key file authentication. By default key file authentication will enable client authentication. Just specifying key file for all mongod instance is enough.